# Can you pressure cook whole fish and get soft bones without overcooking fish?

Tags: fish, pressure-cooker, bones

I want to cook whole fish in a soup and get the bones soft.  According to some answers pressure cooking will soften bones.  however by the time this has happened won't the fish meat be overcooked/tear off the bones?

How long should it be in a pressure cooker for and at what setting?

Comment: any idea how long i should do it for, won't the meat tear off even if it doesnt dry up?

Comment: It will be very difficult to come up with one right answer because 1) there are many types of pressure cooker and 2) there are many types of fish, with varying size and varying flesh .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to a related question: [How to cook a fish to make it's bones soft](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10439/how-to-cook-a-fish-to-make-its-bone-as-soft-as-those-in-sardines/10441#10441)

Basically, the pressure cooking doesn't allow any moisture to escape the system so the fish will retain the moisture and not dry out. It will still reach a hot temperature inside the can, which may result in a slightly different texture than if you were to sous vide, for example. But the pressure cooking should soften the bones and be the solution you are looking for.